# How can I make this script faster?

Tags: macos, applescript, automation

Below is a script intended to press the up arrow key every time a pixel of `#535353` is encountered at `555,888`. This is intended to create a bot for the Chrome dino game. However, for some reason the script does not always successfully press the up arrow when a cactus passes through `555,888`. I reason this to be because the script isn't running the shell command to test the pixel frequently enough. 
Is there a more efficient way to test for the color of an onscreen pixel such that I can test for it more times per second?

```
repeat
    set px to ""
    set px to (do shell script "screencapture -R555,888,1,1 -t bmp $TMPDIR/test.bmp && 
             xxd -p -l 3 -s 54 $TMPDIR/test.bmp | 
             sed 's/\\(..\\)\\(..\\)\\(..\\)/\\3\\2\\1/'")
    if px contains "535353" then
         tell application "System Events"
            key code 126
         end tell
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: Consider using a graphical automation tool like http://up.csail.mit.edu/sikuli/ Sadly the Sikuli web site seems unreachable thanks to a poorly configured `iframe`.